How can I change order of camera lists in Windows 11?
I have been using many apps that has camera-related feature. Because of that, my PC has many camera drivers installed.
The problem is, when I try to use camera on some of the webpages, the default camera is not set as my laptop's camera.
If the page doesn't support choosing cameras, I have to manually disable other camera devices, which is quite annoying.
The question is;

How does Windows handle order when there is multiple cameras?

Can I change the order manually? If yes, how can I do it?



The issue is not so much the order of the cameras in the list, but which camera was last used (or is still in use). It has nothing to do with camera drivers. Further, some applications keep their own lists. For example, I've noticed that once I've used a camera in Zoom Workplace, if the camera is unplugged, the internal webcam is used, but when the external camera is connected, Zoom automatically uses it, instead.
So to set a particular camera as default, do so in the application.

In Firefox, open Tools > Settings (or Edit > Preferences in Linux), type perm in the search box to view Permissions, remove the website from camera and microphone, refresh the video conference, and select the camera when reconnecting.

For Microsoft Edge, do the same at Settings > Site Permissions > Camera and Settings > Site Permissions > Microphone.

For Google Chrome browser, do the same at Menu > Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Camera and Menu > Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Microphone.


Hopefully, the browser will remember the correct input devices, but, if not, you can choose 'em again. However, having to disconnect from the meeting session and reconnect is a nuisance.
Instead, rather than using a web browser, use a dedicated application for video conferences, such as Zoom Workplace,

or Google Meet,

that offers selection of input devices.

Can you explain to me about 'last used' cameras? would list of cameras in browser's drop-down menu change if I use cameras on other apps?

Each app has it's own list. In addition, when a camera is disconnected, it likely would be removed from that list if that app is running. Since each web browser and dedicated teleconference app is different, there's no general rule.
